# Custom Controls within Panels within aspx pages. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Long time listener, first time caller!

I have an ASXP page that has a panel.  When I click a button on the master ASPX page some code is run that loads a custom ascx control into the panel.  When the master page initially loads a "home" control is loaded.  When a button on the master page is clicked, the home control is cleared and another control is loaded.  The problem is that when I click on a link label in the custom control all of a sudden the custom control is unloaded and the home control is re-loaded.

It looks something like this (Im sorry if this is hard to read.)

**Master Page - home.aspx - ASP**

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID=”link1” runat=”server” OnClick=”Load_Control2” /></td>
            <td><asp:Panel ID=”Panel1” runat=”server” /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Master Page - home.aspx – C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl control =(PageControls.Control1)LoadControl("PathtoControl");
    ApplicationDock.Controls.Add(control);    
}
protected void Load_Control2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationDock.Controls.Clear();
    UserControl control =(PageControls.Control2)LoadControl("PathtoControl");
    ApplicationDock.Controls.Add(control);    
}
```

**Custom Control1 – ASCX – ASP**

```
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><h2> Welcome Home </h2></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**Custom Control2 – ASCX – ASP**

```
<div>
    <asp:LinkButton ID=”CustomLink1” runat=”Server” Onclick=”RunClodeBlock1” />
</div>
```

**Custom Control2 – ASCX – C#**

```
Protected void RunClodeBlock1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.redirect(“google.com”);
}
```

Comment: When you click on CustomLink1 on ASCX file, the application execute the Page_Load method on home.aspx?

Comment: You are correct.  how do I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just doing it all wrong.  I have ditched the ascx controls and I am now using a master page with additional aspx content pages.

My approach was nothing more than a carry over from a bad habit I have in WPF.